# Write-write conflict everytime saving a Apps Script File on Eclipse

Tags: google-apps-script, google-eclipse-plugin

I'm started using Google Eclipse Plugin, on Eclipse Indigo, to edit apps script and everything is working as expected, except that everytime I save a file, I get this popup the warning:

[image]

The file is shared but nobody else is editing or even opened on the web.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is interesting indeed. Are you using a Drive Sync client on any machines associated with that account? Trying to figure out what might cause this.

Comment: I just had one drive client installed on the same machine and other on an android device, but even removing all collaborators of the script and disabling all drive clients sync, the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.

**Mac OS X and Eclipse Indigo**

The problem was because of the Text File Encoding. On Mac OS X with **Eclipse Indigo** the default Text File Encoding is set to MacRoman. I suppose Apps Scripts are in UTF-8. When I set the default Text File Encoding to UTF-8 the problem was gone.

**Mac OS X Mavericks and Eclipse Kepler**

Default text encoding is already set to UTF-8.

To fix set `Default Encoding` = `UTF-8` in *Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JavaScript Source File > Apps Scripts Source file*.

[image: Eclipse Kepler preferences]

Comment: Could you log a bug here - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: Done:https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3349&thanks=3349&ts=1382998092

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have answered "Yes" to "Save to Drive anyway?" but are still getting this message the next time you try to save.

Check whether your version of the file on Drive is in fact up-to-date. If it is, you can try synchronizing in the other direction: Right-click on the the project in the Package Explorer and select Google > Update Apps Script project from Drive on the dropdown menu.

Comment: I answered "Yes". Even updating or removing and adding the project again the problem persists.